# How to make 15 days bunch array within 2 different dates in PHP?

Tags: php, function, date, datetime, datediff

Below is the output which I want in php.

Suppose I pass the two different dates in a function.

lets say I passed "`01/01/2016 to 07/25/2016`" Into function

```
function bunch_days15($date1, $date2){
}
```

How do I get the below results of 15 days set ?

```
array{

  [0] => {

           [0] 01/01/2016
           [1] 01/15/2016
         }

  [1] => {

         [0] 01/16/2016
         [1] 01/31/2016
  }

  [2] => {

           [0] 02/01/2016
           [1] 02/15/2016

         }

  [3] => {

         [0] 02/16/2016
         [1] 02/28/2016
  }
}
```

And soo

Please let me know through common functions in which I passed 2 different dates and it will return array in the bunch of 15 days results.

Comment: A valid function name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. So change your `function 15daysBunch($date1, $date2)` to a valid one.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the updates..

Comment: @montupepavanshi 1+15 should be 16 right how again 15? similarly 17+15

Comment: Anything.. 15 or 16. i want half monthly array in 2 different parts for that month.

Comment: So you want to divide the month into half right?

Comment: Yes right but in a specific way  like in same array no other month will come..!!

Comment: how you get first and last dates for example if you give start date 2016-01-25 and end date 2016-06-01 then it will include january month and june month or not.

Comment: I am passing always start date as 1st jan or 1st feb and so on. and for the last date, i will pass anything say 25th june or 20th june

Answer (score 0):

```
function daysBunch($date1, $date2){
    $temp_date = $date1;
    $days = array();
    $i = 0;
    while(1){
        $next_date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("$temp_date +14 days"));
        if(strtotime($next_date) > strtotime($date2)){
            break;
        }
        $days[$i][] = $temp_date;
        $days[$i][] = $next_date;
        $temp_date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("$next_date +1 days"));
        $i++;
    }
    return $days;
}

$d1 = "01/01/2016";
$d2 = "07/25/2016";
var_dump(daysBunch($d1, $d2));
```

N.B: For starting date 01/1/2016 it will give you 01/15/2016 similarly for 01/16/2016 it will show 01/30/2016.

Comment: Some last days are not coming in calculations.. and i don't want different month in same array. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is my function

```
function bunch_days15($date1, $date2){

$startDate = new DateTime($date1);
$endDate = new DateTime($date2);
$mArray = array();

while ($startDate <= $endDate)
{
    $row = array();
    $row[] =$startDate->format("Y-m-01");
    $row[] = $startDate->format("Y-m-15");

    $mArray[] = $row;

    $row = array();
    $row[] = $startDate->format("Y-m-16");
    $row[] = $startDate->format("Y-m-t");

    $mArray[] = $row;

    $startDate = $startDate->modify( 'first day of next month' );;
}
return $mArray;
```

}

```
print_r(bunch_days15('2015-01-01','2016-06-08'));
```

Comment: It should be independent from year. year could be 2015 or 2014  or so. this will work only for 2016..!! it should work in any year which i pass..

Comment: Check this modified version of my function

Comment: If you pass "2016-06-08'" as last date then its not going above that date!! currently it will include till June 30th, it must include till June 8th..